# prettier Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I just set up eslint and prettier into my existing react project(CSR) and executed 'npm run prettier' then I got errors as below.

How should I solve this error?
FYI, There is src/App.tsx file exists unlike the error below.

```
> ut-admin-web@3.1.0 prettier /Users/jin/projects_new/backup/2021/ut-admin-react-test
> prettier --write --config ./.prettierrc './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'

[error] Invalid configuration file `src/App.tsx`: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../.prettierrc'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! ut-admin-web@3.1.0 prettier: `prettier --write --config ./.prettierrc './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ...@3.1.0 prettier script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

my .prettierrc.json

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "parser": "typescript",
  "semi": false,
  "useTabs": true,
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

my .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "prettier",
        "prettier/react",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "airbnb", 
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

and finally here is my some part of package.json

```
...
...

 "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}'",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}'",
    "prettier": "prettier --write --config ./.prettierrc './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'"

...
```

Answer (score -4):

Move your prettier configuration into a key in `package.json` (and remove the rc file):

```
{
  "dependencies": ...,
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "semi": false,
    "useTabs": true,
    "printWidth": 120
  }
}
```

and simplify your `prettier` script to

```
"prettier": "prettier --write ./src"
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: @JustinEdwards Wish I knew :shrug: